# Visual Studio e Github - Quais arquivos ignorar (C#)

Tags: c#, git, github, visual-studio-2017

Olá!
Estou estudando C# e criei um repositório no Github para guardar os exercícios.

Ao iniciar um novo projeto, o Visual Studio Community (2017) cria a seguinte estrutura:

```
PastaDoProjeto/
    ArquivoProjeto.sln
    OutraPasta/
        Program.cs
        NomeDoPrograma.csproj
        App.config
        Properties/
            AssemblyInfo.cs
        obj/
            Debug/ //Pasta contendo vários arquivos
            Release/ //Pasta vazia
        bin/
            Debug/ //Pasta contendo vários arquivos
            Release/ //Pasta vazia
```

Estou na dúvida sobre quais são os arquivos que eu **devo** adicionar ao git e quais ignorar. Ou seja, **quais são os arquivos imprescindíveis** para que o repositório seja clonado e o programa executado em outra máquina e, quais arquivos e/ou pastas eu posso simplesmente **ignorar** **sem** **prejuízo** para o *"transporte* *do* *programa"*.

Comment: Este site [gitignore.io](https://gitignore.io) é uma ferramenta online que gera arquivos .gitignore de acordo com a linguagem especificada. É uma ferramenta bem útil. Na pagina inicial é só escrever o nome da linguagem e clicar em criar. Para seu caso é só escrever CSharp que ele gera o arquivo .gitignore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Após o processo de compilação de um projeto no `Visual Studio`, os arquivos são geralmente criados nas pastas `/bin` e `/obj` do seu projeto, sendo estas totalmente ignoradas nos meus `gitignore`'s.

Já na internet você pode encontrar vários `gitignore`'s prontos para um tipo de projeto específico como `Windows Forms`, `Asp.NET`, etc.

Abaixo vou deixar um `gitignore` para você testar. (Lembrando que se já subiu os arquivos que estão como exceção no `gitignore`, terá que exclui-los manualmente do seu repositório):

```js
*.suo
*.user
*.sln.docstates

# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Rr]elease/
x64/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/
# build folder is nowadays used for build scripts and should not be ignored
#build/

# NuGet Packages
*.nupkg
# The packages folder can be ignored because of Package Restore
**/packages/*
# except build/, which is used as an MSBuild target.
!**/packages/build/
# Uncomment if necessary however generally it will be regenerated when needed
#!**/packages/repositories.config

# MSTest test Results
[Tt]est[Rr]esult*/
[Bb]uild[Ll]og.*

*_i.c
*_p.c
*.ilk
*.meta
*.obj
*.pch
*.pdb
*.pgc
*.pgd
*.rsp
*.sbr
*.tlb
*.tli
*.tlh
*.tmp
*.tmp_proj
*.log
*.vspscc
*.vssscc
.builds
*.pidb
*.log
*.scc

# OS generated files #
.DS_Store*
Icon?

# Visual C++ cache files
ipch/
*.aps
*.ncb
*.opensdf
*.sdf
*.cachefile

# Visual Studio profiler
*.psess
*.vsp
*.vspx

# Guidance Automation Toolkit
*.gpState

# ReSharper is a .NET coding add-in
_ReSharper*/
*.[Rr]e[Ss]harper

# TeamCity is a build add-in
_TeamCity*

# DotCover is a Code Coverage Tool
*.dotCover

# NCrunch
*.ncrunch*
.*crunch*.local.xml

# Installshield output folder
[Ee]xpress/

# DocProject is a documentation generator add-in
DocProject/buildhelp/
DocProject/Help/*.HxT
DocProject/Help/*.HxC
DocProject/Help/*.hhc
DocProject/Help/*.hhk
DocProject/Help/*.hhp
DocProject/Help/Html2
DocProject/Help/html

# Click-Once directory
publish/

# Publish Web Output
*.Publish.xml

# Windows Azure Build Output
csx
*.build.csdef

# Windows Store app package directory
AppPackages/

# Others
*.Cache
ClientBin/
[Ss]tyle[Cc]op.*
~$*
*~
*.dbmdl
*.[Pp]ublish.xml
*.pfx
*.publishsettings
modulesbin/
tempbin/

# EPiServer Site file (VPP)
AppData/

# RIA/Silverlight projects
Generated_Code/

# Backup & report files from converting an old project file to a newer
# Visual Studio version. Backup files are not needed, because we have git ;-)
_UpgradeReport_Files/
Backup*/
UpgradeLog*.XML
UpgradeLog*.htm

# vim
*.txt~
*.swp
*.swo

# Temp files when opening LibreOffice on ubuntu
.~lock.*
 
# svn
.svn

# CVS - Source Control
**/CVS/

# Remainings from resolving conflicts in Source Control
*.orig

# SQL Server files
**/App_Data/*.mdf
**/App_Data/*.ldf
**/App_Data/*.sdf


#LightSwitch generated files
GeneratedArtifacts/
_Pvt_Extensions/
ModelManifest.xml

# =========================
# Windows detritus
# =========================

# Windows image file caches
Thumbs.db
ehthumbs.db

# Folder config file
Desktop.ini

# Recycle Bin used on file shares
$RECYCLE.BIN/

# Mac desktop service store files
.DS_Store

# SASS Compiler cache
.sass-cache

# Visual Studio 2014 CTP
**/*.sln.ide

# Visual Studio temp something
.vs/

# dotnet stuff
project.lock.json

# VS 2015+
*.vc.vc.opendb
*.vc.db

# Rider
.idea/

# Visual Studio Code
.vscode/

# Output folder used by Webpack or other FE stuff
**/node_modules/*
**/wwwroot/*

# SpecFlow specific
*.feature.cs
*.feature.xlsx.*
*.Specs_*.html

#####
# End of core ignore list, below put you custom 'per project' settings (patterns or path)
#####
```

Fonte: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore

Comment: Só pra eu entender um pouco melhor: Esses arquivos __nome.extensão__ tipo __*.obj__ são os arquivos que o Git vai ignorar é isso?

Comment: Exatamente amigo. Na verdade qualquer `.obj`será ignorado, e não apenas um arquivo com `nome_específico.obj`

Comment: Excelente. Independente de usar o "gerador de gitignore" o arquivo compartilhado já me deu uma boa noção do que incluir (no arquivo).

Answer (score 1):

> Estou na dúvida sobre quais são os arquivos que eu devo adicionar ao git e quais ignorar. Posso (leia-se 'devo') adicionar a pasta do projeto inteiro?

Você pode adicionar o arquivo que quiser. O problema em si é que há arquivos que não fazem parte do desenvolvimento. Esses arquivos devem ser ignorados.

> Em projetos python, ignoro o "pycache". Há algo do tipo no C# visto que o Visual Studio (Community 2017) cria diversas pastas e arquivos?

No caso, você deve focar em todo os arquivos que não são importantes para o desenvolvimento do projeto.

Por exemplo, não faz sentido commitar arquivos de log, pastas temporárias, arquivos compilados, pastas de upload, ou arquivos pertencentes à biblioteca que você está usando.

Neste último caso citado, quando você vai gerenciar bibliotecas do seu projeto, você deve commitar o arquivo responsável por controlar o gerenciamento de versões delas, *e não os arquivos da biblioteca em si*. Por exemplo, em projetos Python ao invés de commitar a pasta `venv` contendo todas as dependências, você deve commitar o `requirements.txt`; no caso do PHP, ao invés de commitar a pasta `vendor`, você deve commitar apenas `composer.json` e `composer.lock`; no caso do ǸPM, você não deve commitar `node_modules`, e sim `package.json`. E assim por diante.

O outro desenvolvedor que for desenvolver junto com você terá, por exemplo, que executar o `npm install` (ou qualquer outro gerenciador de biblioteca da linguagem usada) para instalar as dependências na máquina dele.

Pois os arquivos do `node_modules` *não fazem parte do projeto*, são apenas usados por ele como dependência.

**Resumindo**

Não se concentre em ter uma  fórmula mágica ou apenas procurar copiar e colar da internet o padrão a ser seguido para um `.gitignore` de um projeto.

Para fortalecer a ideia, eis uma tradução da própria documentação do `GIT`:

> Padrões que devem ser controlados por versão e distribuídos para outros repositórios via clone (ou seja, arquivos que todos os desenvolvedores desejarão ignorar) devem entrar em um arquivo `.gitignore`.

Um exemplo claro do que está descrito acima é um arquivo `.env` (usado em algumas linguagens para definir configurações locais de aplicação). Não faz sentido adicionar isso ao seu repositório, uma vez que ele possui configurações do seu banco de dados local. Se você enviar tal arquivo num commit, toda hora o desenvolvedor que estiver trabalhando com você vai ter que ficar editando e consertando a configuração do banco de dados.

Comment: Quando diz "Não se concentre em ter uma fórmula mágica ou apenas procurar copiar e colar da internet... " quer dizer que escreve todos os seus `gitgnores` cada caractere? Só não vejo necessidade de reinventar a roda, porque já tem pronto na internet, o que quiser é só personalizar. Apenas minha humilde opinião.

Comment: "Já tem pronto na internet" leva você apenas a copiar e colar, porém sem entender o objetivo de existir o gitignore. O tais "prontos na internet" que você citou, só funciona pra projetos que tem estrutura conhecida. Se ele tiver usando um framework próprio ou fazendo em estrutura alternativa, é mais importante saber fazer do que copiar e colar

Comment: Mas quando o autor diz "Estou na dúvida sobre quais são os arquivos que eu devo adicionar ao git e quais ignorar" ele já não entende o objetivo? Deveria frisar em sua resposta que o objetivo de não copiar da internet é um meio de aprender colocando a mão na massa pois nós desenvolvedores sabemos que isso não funciona na prática, a não ser que você queira.

Comment: Não. Meu objetivo foi treinar a cabeça dele pra saber, sem precisar de ter uma "receita de bolo", como proceder para ignorar os arquivos. Não há problemas copiar e colar, mas é importante entender onde o gitignore deve ser usado. O objetivo da resposta foi ser genérica e ser usada pra qualquer linguagem, já que o objetivo do site é fazer que uma dúvida específica possa ser usado pra ajudar outros programadores

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Entendo e agradeço a sua intenção, entretanto, não responde a minha pergunta... Eu conheço algumas "soluções prontas" como o gitignore.io e encontrei alguns "modelos" como aquele compartilhado pelo autor da resposta anterior. Entretanto, conforme a pergunta, estou estudando C# agora, ainda não tenho conhecimento sobre o que é cada pasta e arquivo, então o que quero saber é qual delas são fundamentais e quais são "descartáveis" para um repositório no github. Ou, em simetria oposta, quais são de envio fundamental.

Comment: Qual é o framework que você está usando?

Comment: Nenhum (nada além do .NET)... são basicamente estudos em linha de comando.